# Reverse SSH tunnel daemon

Tags: terminal, network, wifi, ssh

I own a Macintosh laptop (10.11.2) that I would like to create a permanent reverse SSH tunnel.

This way, when I switch network, or the computer is stolen, I can remotely SSH into the device independent on what network it is on.

Currently, I run this command from when I am on the laptop, but if my network gets interrupted, I have to run it again.

```
ssh -N -R 2000:localhost:22 root@my_server_ip
```

(and then run `ssh -p 2000 localhost` on my home server)

But if my laptop switches network, or I am not physically on it to run the command, the reverse SSH tunnel does not work.

Is there any mac command line solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is `autossh` doing exactly what you need:

```
autossh -M 12345 -N -R 2000:localhost:22 root@my_server_ip
```

But you should certainly reconsider running the tunnel using `root` account, when it is password-less (unless you have the key limited using `authorized_commands`).